# Audit changes with trigger for SQL Server manual changes and EF Core 6 changes

Tags: sql-server, triggers, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, audit

I need to create a row in my `UserAduit` table. But need to record the changes done by my application via EF Core 6, when the changes are coming from the app. And if the table is updated by using a SQL script using SSMS.

Comment: So your question is how to write a trigger to insert into your `UserAudit` table?... I assume this is to audit your `Users` table only? Can you please provide the schema of your `Users` table?